# Spring configuration and registering interceptors

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have the below spring XML file to which I am upgrading to new spring 5 version. Below are the tags.

```
<mvc:interceptors>

        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
            <bean id="responseHeadersInterceptor" class="munlife.mvc.framework.interceptor.ResponseHeadersInterceptor" />
        </mvc:interceptor>

        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
            <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/helloworld/goodbye"/> <!-- Don't start new sessions on the goodbye method -->
            <bean id="sessionInitInterceptor" class="ca.munlife.web.apps.exampleapp.interceptor.SessionInitInterceptor" />
        </mvc:interceptor>

        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
            <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
                class="munlife.mvc.framework.ValidatingLocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="locale" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>

        <bean id="handlerMappingInterceptor" class="munlife.mvc.framework.interceptor.HandlerMappingInterceptor" />


    </mvc:interceptors>
```

I want to write them to a class as I am upgrading the new spring 5, so how can I remove them from XML file? I am thinking to add a class in such a way:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.boraji.spring.controller" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
      // ****** please advise how here i can add interceptor responseHeadersInterceptor ***


       public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
      // ***** please advise how here i can add interceptor sessionInitInterceptor ***
   }

    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
      // ***** please advise how here i can add interceptor localeChangeInterceptor ***
   } 

   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
   // ***** please advise how here i can add interceptor handlerMappingInterceptor ***
   } 


}
```

I want to remove the legacy spring framework approach and convert it into spring 5 version. I want to remove XML mapping and want to convert it to a new approach. How to achieve that?

Comment: We are not a code writing service, what have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.boraji.spring.controller" })
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

       @Override
       public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new ResponseHeadersInterceptor()) 
        registry.addInterceptor(new SessionInitInterceptor()) .addPathPatterns("/**") .excludePathPatterns("/helloworld/goodbye");
        ValidatingLocaleChangeInterceptor  validatingLocaleChangeInterceptor = new  ValidatingLocaleChangeInterceptor();
        validatingLocaleChangeInterceptor.setParamName("locale");
        registry.addInterceptor(validatingLocaleChangeInterceptor);
       }
```

Comment: Thanks but please advise what about sessionInitInterceptor which contain <mvc:exclude-mapping path="/helloworld/goodbye"/> <!-- Don't start new sessions on the goodbye method -->

Comment: also please advise what about localeChangeInterceptor how I will add parameters in class as in XML they are in form  <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
            <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
                class="munlife.mvc.framework.ValidatingLocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="locale" />
            </bean>